# Generalized method that compares old and new content from different sources

Tags: c#, refactoring

I send three http requests to a web service every 10th second. The reponses are handed off to three methods in a cache class (one for each http query / request) that checks whether the reponse content has changed since last time.

I convert the raw reponse content to a string and compare it to the old response, which is stored as a private string in the cache class. It works alright, but the approach has a lot of duplicate code, as you can see:

```
    class Cache
{
    private HubClient _hubClient;
    private string oldIncidentAppointment;
    private string oldIncidentGeneral;
    private string oldIncidentUntreated;

    public Cache(HubClient hubClient)
    {
        _hubClient = hubClient;
    }

    public bool IsIncidentAppointmentNew(string currentIncidentAppointment)
    {
        if (XElement.Equals(oldIncidentAppointment, currentIncidentAppointment))
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            oldIncidentAppointment = currentIncidentAppointment;
            _hubClient.SendToHub();
            return true;
        }
    }

    public bool IsIncidentUntreatedNew(string currentIncidentUntreated)
    {
        if (XElement.Equals(oldIncidentUntreated, currentIncidentUntreated))
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            oldIncidentUntreated = currentIncidentUntreated;
            _hubClient.SendToHub();
            return true;
        }
    }

    public bool IsIncidentGeneralNew(string currentIncidentGeneral)
    {
        if (XElement.Equals(oldIncidentGeneral, currentIncidentGeneral))
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            oldIncidentGeneral = currentIncidentGeneral;
            _hubClient.SendToHub();
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

How can this be refactored into a generalized method that compares old and new content for all my current and future http query methods?

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking the same thing. But this approach requires me to hard code the values in the dictionary and is therefore not very extensible. What other options do I have? Func?

Comment: What do you mean hardcoding in the dictionary? The dictionary would map arbitrary amount (within memory limits of course) of arbitrary strings to arbitrary web page contents.

Comment: I can see what you mean, I was thinking about it the wrong way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store them in a dictionary:

```
class Cache {

    private HubClient _hubClient;
    private Dictionary<string, string> _pages;


    public Cache(HubClient hubClient)
    {
        _hubClient = hubClient;
        _pages = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    }

    public bool isPageNew( string key, string content ) {
        string current;
        if (_pages.TryGetValue(key, out current) && XElement.Equals(current, content)) {
            return false;
        }

        _pages[key] = content;
        _hubClient.SendToHub(); //Why have side effect here? :P
        return true;
    }
}
```

Then:

```
Cache cache = new Cache( client );

if( cache.isPageNew( "untreated", pageContent ) ) {

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What do you mean with "side effect"?

Comment: @user1750323 well the function suggests that it gives you a yes or no answer to something. But it also has a side effect (doing some IO?) that is not obvious to the caller.

Answer (score 1):

This is quick and dirty, so if it's not 100% you'll have to fix it up; I don't have your tests to verify it's correctness.   I'm also not sure you can just ask a dictionary for a key that doesn't exist without checking for it's existence, so you might have to handle that.

```
class Cache
{
    private HubClient _hubClient;
    private IDictionary<string, string> _oldIncidents;

    public Cache(HubClient hubClient)
    {
        _hubClient = hubClient;
        _oldIncidents = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    }

    public bool IsIncidentAppointmentNew(string currentIncidentAppointment)
    {
        return DoMagicWork(
            incidentKey: "appointment",
            currentIncident = currentIncidentAppointment
        );
    }

    public bool IsIncidentUntreatedNew(string currentIncidentUntreated)
    {
        return DoMagicWork(
            incidentKey: "untreated",
            currentIncident = currentIncidentUntreated
        );
    }

    public bool IsIncidentGeneralNew(string currentIncidentGeneral)
    {
        return DoMagicWork(
            incidentKey: "general",
            currentIncident = currentIncidentGeneral
        );
    }

    private bool DoMagicWork(string incidentKey, string currentIncident)
    {
        var oldIncident = _oldIncidents[incidentKey];
        if (XElement.Equals(oldIncident, currentIncident))
        {
            return false;
        }

        _oldIncidents[incidentKey] = currentIncident;
        _hubClient.SendToHub();
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, seems like a good solution. Do you think using Func<> or similar could be used to achieve the same thing? Im mainly asking out of curiosity.

Comment: You could do anything I imagine, but since it's all the same function, I don't see much use for it.  If I were to use a function it would be because different cache items needed different cache strategies or some other custom handling, but all of these were the same.